# How to calculate the performance parameters of an hexacopter (UAV)?

Tags: unmanned-aerial-vehicle, performance-calculation

I need to calculate the performance parameters like cruise speed, endurance, range of my hexacopter but how can I do that!

Also, is there a way to obtain motor-propeller performance parameters without using a load cell?

Comment: Welcome to Aviation.SE! I would suggest you start by reading the [help] to get an idea for how this site works. You should generally try to ask one specific question at a time and provide as much detail as possible, including what you already know and what you have tried. As it currently stands, your question is likely to be closed. You could prevent this by using the edit button to improve your question.

Answer (score 1):

The way it's done in helicopters is by using power vs speed curves, comparing required power and available power. You would need to compute:

- Rotor induced power
- Rotor profile power
- Fuselage aerodynamic drag power
- Tail rotor & transmission power (probably  not applicable in your case)
- Power loss from friction, electrical heat etc.

[image]

Total power to remain airborne is a function of gross weight, air density, rotor state, aircraft state and velocity vectors.

There is a way to measure delivered power of an electric motor, I assume that is what your copter uses: measure delivered amperage for the applied torque, measure voltage over the motor for rotational velocity, and multiply the two for applied electrical power.